# query mysql database by field and return all occurrences

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table in my database that has these fields:

```
-id
-video_title
-video_article
-video_category
```

Now, I'd like to query it by video_category and I have tried this code so far:

```
public function related_videos($current_video_category)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM English WHERE video_category = :current_video_category";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt->execute(array(":current_video_category" => $current_video_category));
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $data;
}
```

The problem is it returns the first occurrence only and I'm not sure how to return all the occurrences of `$current_video_category` at once.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only fetch one row:

```
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If you want to fetch all available rows from the statement, use `fetchAll`:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This returns an array where each element is a row from the query.

Comment: fetchAll works like a charm for me! thanks @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that fetch assoc in while loop to get all data

```
While($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

//process data here

}
```